# You start with five dice. Roll all the dice and put aside those dice that come up as a 6. Markov chain in python

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

You start with five dice. Roll all the dice and put aside those dice that come up 6. Then, roll the remaining dice, putting aside those dice that come up 6. And so on, until no dice are left.

Using  $10^{5}$  experiments, estimate the probability that it will take more than 10 rounds to end this game.

Hello, I am working on this Markov chain problem in Python and I was wondering if someone could help me out. My initial thought process was to set up the transition matrix using binomial theorem and then calculate $1-[P_{[0,5]}+P^{2}_{[0,5]}+\cdots+ P^{10}_{[0,5]}]$. The issue I found with that was it wasn't specifically $10^5$ experiments. I cant really think of any other way to solve this

Comment: Your states are $s_0,\dots,s_5 $ where $s_k$ is the state where you are rolling $k$ dice next round, Then $s_k\to s_n$ where $n\leq k$ with probability $$\binom{k}n\frac{5^n}{6^k}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thats how i did the transition matrix P but was unable to figure out how to do 10^5 simulations in python

Comment: It seems strange to ask for a simulation. We can get a recursion, if $X_k$ is the number of rolls starting with $k$ dice:, the $E(X_0)=0,$ and $E(X_k)=1+\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn\frac{5^n}{6^k}E(X_n)$ or $$E(X_k)=\frac{6^k}{6^k-5^k}+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\binom kn\frac{5^n}{6^k-5^k}E(X_n)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following $10^5$ times:

```
counter <- 0

x <- (1,1,1,1,1)

repeat

Multiply each of the five components of this vector by
0 with probability 1/6 and increment the counter by 1.

until the sum of the five components in x is 0.
```

Run that $10^5$ times and see in how many of those $10^5$ times the counter is more than $10$ when the repeat-until loop ends.